# how to share object schema between client and REST service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

As we know we  don't have to take service reference or no proxy require at client side to talk to REST service. but the question is how come the client would know what object to send to service, as client doesn't have object schema, if it has to send serialised object XML/JSON what should be the object schema???

Comment: Usually if a service does not expose its meta data, there is documentation that describes the format. Alternatively client and service may share a library that contains this information.

Comment: if that so than it similar to having proxy/service reference, than what would be the benefit of using REST service?

Comment: A web service exposes _methods_, REST exposes _resources_. It's a different thing, used in different situations.

Comment: So it would be right to say it is not complete replacement of regular WCF service?

Comment: It can be a complete replacement for WCF - but its very different, not a technology, more a methodology. I would recommend reading "REST in practice" (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805838.do)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from the tags in your question that you are using WCF, you can place your service and data CONTRACTS (not service implementations) in a shared assembly that your client application(s) and service depend on.

If your client is making a non-SOAP call (to a "webHttpBinding" endpoint), you can manually serialise the appropriate data contract to POST to the server using a DataContractSerializer.

If you need to post XML from a client where you don't have access to a DataContractSerializer (a non .NET client), you need to construct the input by hand. So at the very least, you would need to serialise your data contract and use the result as documentation for constructing the input message by hand from the client.

RESTful "get" requests are like fetching resources based on identifiers so you would normally not need to serialise or construct by hand some complex XML or json structure.

Please also note that not all non-SOAP services are RESTful.